# Kali Linux: Screen lock --> weird sleep mode

Tags: linux, sleep, kali-linux, lock-screen

I am running Kali Linux with the Xfce desktop environment (dual boot with Win10) on a Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga 370.

Xfce version: 4.14

First issue:
Whenever I lock my screen, my laptop goes into some kind of sleep mode. Is it possible to just make the password prompt appear?

Second issue:
When using an external monitor over HDMI and having the laptop screen closed the sleep mode doesn't "activate" and I am stuck with a black screen until I reopen the laptop screen which then activates the sleep mode. After this a simple mouse click is enough the wake it up again.

Anyone who had similar issues?

Thanks in advance,
Basti

Comment: For the first question, look in XFce Power Manager, Security. I have: Auto lock when screensaver is activated, display locking: 5 seconds and then Lock screen when suspending enabled. Set this way, Manual Lock Screen just give Password Prompt as you wish. Kali 2020.1 and XFce that goes with it.

Comment: The settings are exactly as described by you, doesn't work for me tho...
When using only my laptop screen (no external stuff) and locking the screen it turns black, a white cursor appears for a second and then the screen turns off into some kind of sleep mode.
How can I disable this sleep mode? When selecting "switch user" instead of "lock screen" it just get prompted with the login, this is basically what I want

Comment: I am using just one monitor. However, In Kali Power Settings, under System, you can set the slider left to Never and turn suspend OFF. I have it set the other way to 5 Hours and that basically serves the same function.

Comment: Ye I know, I have set all the sliders to "Never". Tbh I don't think this has something to do with the power saving settings and rather with the behavior of Kali Linux with a second monitor. When using only the laptop this issue isn't a big deal as it goes directly to sleep and I can wake it up using any key, but when using the second monitor with my laptop closed the sleep mode doesn't activate until I open my laptop, then it can be woken up again...

Comment: I am not sure and will keep looking. There is a Display configuration in Settings to add a display, but I do not see where this affects Suspend. Look there in any event

Comment: I played around with it quite a bit but didn't find what I was searching for. My workaround for the moment is that I swapped the lock button for a switch user button which brings me to the login screen as well, just here I have to type in my username aswell, which is fine for the moment. Will have a look into the whole problem again when I have more time, but thanks a lot for your suggestions :) If I find a solution I will ofc post it here.