# Lockscreen shows black screen on Kali linux multimonitor setup

Tags: linux, sleep, kali-linux, lock-screen, xfce4

In Kali Linux 2020.3 with XFCE4 installed whenever I lock the screen on my 3 monitor setup I get a blank screen. However if I type the password in blindly, it logs me in, altough it doesn't work 100% of the time.

This is also the same issue mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1522790/kali-linux-screen-lock-weird-sleep-mode) but since I don't have enough reputation I can't answer it. I decided to ask state the question and answer it myself instead.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of digging I found that it's actually an XFCE4 issue.
Upon lock `/usr/bin/xflock4` is called which is just a script with a bunch of lock commands.
For me it was the case that `light-locker-command --lock` simply doesn't work with multi monitors.

The solution is to simply install `xscreensaver` and it will take precedence over the `light-locker-command`. Make sure you execute `xscreensaver -nosplash` and also add it to in Session and Startup for this to work.

Note: If the command `xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /general/LockCommand` returns something else than not empty, then that should be configured instead to your favorite lock app.